# Is a "What is this type of sound called?" question on topic?

Tags: discussion

Technically, it isn't a programming question, and it isn't necessarily even specific to game development. However, in order to find a certain sound, you'd have to know what it was called. For instance, this is the question I had in mind:

> There is a sound typically associated with a bright flash of light,
>   which starts with a lower whirring noise, then breaks into a higher
>   pitched sound. What is that type of sound called?

So, would that be on topic, or off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's a specifically game-related sound, I think it would be relevant.